# x86 assembly: Compare DWORD variable

Tags: assembly, x86

I have a program which opens some file, reads its contents, and outputs it on-screen, along with its length in bytes.

Writing the contents on-screen is no problem, but I can't write a length value greater than `655350` because I have a common procedure which divides the number stored in `dx:ax` by 10 before printing it.

The biggest number I can print this way is `655350`, because greater values won't fit into 16 bits of `ax` after dividing by 10, and will call `int 0h` which is divide-by-zero error.

What I want to do is check if the number in a DWORD variable `number`  is greater than `655350` and, if it is, output a message like "I can't write such a large number". For my assignment, I have to be able to process files up to 128KB, but I want to handle errors if someone attempts to load for ex. 1GB file.

This is some kind of pseudocode what I want to do:

```
filesiz dd ?

call getsize         ;using function 42h which moves pointer of file from beginning to end of file and returns size in bytes in dx:ax registers
mov word ptr[filesiz],ax
mov word ptr[filesiz]+2,dx

call printsize       ;here I want to check if in variable filesiz isn't number grater than 655350
```

NOTE: Of course max number my procedure can print is not `655350` but `655359`. After divide by 10 in ax is still max possible number 65535 and in dx is reminder 9. But answer posted solve problem with number `655350`. If you want solution for `655359` it is simple you just use first `cmp dx,09h`.

Comment: Please [show us a small example of your code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can reproduce the problem. By the way, which assembler are you using, and is your program written using [AT&T-style or Intel-style syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_assembly_language#Syntax)?

Comment: The 32-bit registers have been available since the 80386. Are you targeting something older than that?

Comment: I use Intel-style syntax, 16 bit registers. And really don't know which part of code should I have to paste here. My code is useless for you. I think I described clearly what I want. But If you want it much I can describe it little bit more but code is not needed.

Comment: @Michael I use just 16bit registers and also functions. I know it sound crazy but I think it should be done this way. I don't know how maybe using sbb function or something like that which is making substraction using flags

Comment: Your pseudocode cannot return a value larger than `dx:ax` so that is a problem right there.

Comment: @Jongware What do you mean that it cannot return value larger then dx:ax? Thats clear, I want result in dx:ax. call getsize return value of max size 32 bit (dx:ax) which is 4GB but my procedure printsize can print max number 655350 stored in dx:ax. After first division by 10 i get 0 to dx and 65535 to ax - when in dx:ax will be greater number quotient will be greater than 65535 so it can't be moved to ax register and int 0h will be called.

Comment: For what you want, you may be able to just check `dx` and bail out if it's greater than 1. To print a bigger number, swap `ax` out to another register (or memory location), mov `dx` to `ax`, zero `dx` and divide that by ten. Leave that remainder in `dx`, swap `ax` back in (swapping the quotient out), divide by ten again. This time you've got a useful digit in `dl` - do something intelligent with it. Repeat until done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is to compare DX:AX with 655350 which written in hex is 0009FFF6h

```
call getsize
mov word ptr[filesiz],ax
mov word ptr[filesiz]+2,dx

cmp dx,0009h
ja  NOK
jb  OK
cmp ax,0FFF6h
ja  NOK
OK:
call printsize
```